# C++ pointer and reference with new keyword when instantiating

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

When I want to instantiate a class in C++ I usually go this way

```
Book bk = new Book();
```

My professor recently did this

```
Book &bk = *new Book();
```

He only told me that he would use a reference to be able to use the dot (eg bk.getTitle();) operator instead of arrow (eg bk->getTitle();). I understand this part of the code but what happens when you use the * operator in combination with new?

Thanks in advance

the full example code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Lg2YVME5) it is the arraystack in the main function

Comment: So your professor showed you how to leak memory, great.

Comment: If your professor uses that code for anything other than as an example of something that you really really shouldn't do, then you should find a new professor.

Comment: Probably your professor said, `const Book &bk = Book();`. If that is not the case, I honestly don't understand what your professor meant.

Comment: @Mahesh : The syntax in the question is valid, it's the semantics that are extremely misguided.

Comment: the full example can be found here. maybe this makes more sense then. the part is in the main function. its the arraystack. [source](http://pastebin.com/Lg2YVME5)

Comment: @ildjarn I understand now. But with that syntax, can I do - `delete bk;`. Isn't a case where memory leak is inevitable?

Comment: @Mahesh You could do `delete &bk`, but this is still non-sense.
@OP Find a new professor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This:

```
Book &bk = *new Book();
```

is pretty much equivalent to this:

```
Book *p = new Book();  // Pointer to new book
Book &bk = *p;  // Reference to that book
```

But there's one crucial difference; in the original code, you don't have a pointer which you can use to `delete` the dynamically-allocated object when you're done with it, so you've effectively created a memory leak.

Of course, you could do this:

```
delete &bk;
```

but that's **extremely** non-idiomatic C++, and very likely to cause problems later.

In summary, there's absolutely no good reason to write code like this, so **don't do it**.  Either of the following is fine:

```
Book bk;
Book bk = Book();
```

Comment: thank you I think I will not use it then. The class is more about design patterns than it is about c++ so I will just ignore this programming style and do it my way.

Comment: You have definitely not created a memory leak though, I think that's a huge overstatement

Comment: @Seth : The original code does indeed have a leak... What do you mean?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That's why I said "effectively".  But the need to write things like insanities such as `delete &bk` leads to all sorts of semantic issues, which in turn will lead to forgetting to clean something up somewhere down the line.

Comment: what issues could `delete &bk;` cause? just out of curiosity.

Comment: I see this is ages old, but there *is* a good reason to do it: If the object Book is too large to fit on the stack, so you want it created on the heap, but you don't want to change all your code to use -> instead of .

Answer (score 0):

I've found a situation that let me think about that syntax. Consider a smart pointer to a `Base` class and that has to hold a pointer to a derived class and you would like to access some non-virtual things of the derived class after the construction. In this case something like this is legal and may not be so bad:

```
Derived & d = * new Derived();

d.d_method( ..whatever.. );
d.d_member = ..whatever..;
...

std::unique_ptr<Base> p( &d );
```

Finally I still preferred the small arrows to the weird ampersands:

```
Derived d = new Derived();

d->d_method( ..whatever.. );
d->d_member = ..whatever..;
...

std::unique_ptr<Base> p( d );
```

But I think that in this a case is just a matter of taste, especially if you access a consistent number of methods.

Other things that lead either to leaks or `delete &d;` are just bad, bad, bad.

Comment: `error: Conversion from 'Derived*' to non-scalar type 'Derived' requested`

Comment: @Sebi2020 Yes, a pointer cannot be implicitly converted to its base type. I may have forgotten a `*` or something on the line that triggers the error.